# How to target specific arch during iphone universal(arm6/arm7) build

Tags: iphone, xcode, compiler-construction, xcconfig

Im trying to define different ld and c flags for different arch.

im using this..

OTHER_CFLAGS[sdk=iphoneos*][arch=arm6] = blabla

and whatever is set here doesnt make it into the build.. even setting as arm7 doesnt make a difference.

Tested on both arm6 and arm7 devices.

BTW im using .xcconfigs for my project.

Comment: oh, well looks like it was a typo.. armv6 not arm6
DOH!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that you're using .xcconfigs, but if you want to do this within the build settings interface in Xcode, go to your build settings and select the particular option you want.  Go to the menu at the bottom-left of the screen and choose the `Add Build Setting Condition` option.  In the new build setting condition, choose ARMv6 for the architecture, set what you want for that architecture, add another condition, choose ARMv7 for its architecture, and set what you want for the case of that architecture.

Comment: Yea once i have put things in xcconfigs it displays in build panel so i can see what id need to type if i were to not use them. Problem with the arch was all that they listed in dropdown by default was intel so i wasnt even sure i could target the specific arch at that point or if there was some wacky apple magic going on during the compile.